# In spring/mvc using if-then-else statement on the "model" in a jsp page

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

i've this methodo in my servlet:

```
@Override
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    [...do something...]

    model.put("msg","a message");

    return new ModelAndView("myPage", "model", myModel);

}
```

Now in my myPage.jsp i want to do an if-then-else on ${model.msg} and i've tryed to use JSTL in this way:

```
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${!empty model.msg}">
                <p> not empty </p>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <p>empty</p>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
```

But i get this warning and error: "test does not support run time expressions"

can i've some help? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this,

```
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${not empty msg}">
                <p> not empty </p>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <p>empty</p>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
```

Also, 
you must import JSTL 1.1 if not done.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: ? I've seen ${!empty model.field} work... Is it a difference of maven dependency / tag-lib import?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the latest maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>jstl</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
```